# Prevent Libreoffice converted CSV from stripping trailing zero?

Tags: export-to-csv, precision, libreoffice, floating-accuracy, libreoffice-calc

I have a Calc spreadsheet containing `=ROUND(1.001,2)` which results in **1.00** when formatted as a number with `-1234.57` (aka Format code `0.00`)

However, when I convert it to CSV via `libreoffice --convert-to csv` the trailing `0` are removed resulting in `1`.  How can I get the proper `1.00` output into the CSV?

Note: If I increase precision `=ROUND(1.001,3)`, then the expected `1.001` is output.

Converting single cells explicitly to TEXT (eg `=TEXT(ROUND(1.001,2), "0.00")`) works, but I would like something that works at the document level as this is quite error-prone / tedious.

Comment: Export it as text, because the numeric value `1.00` is equal to the numeric value `1`, so there is no need to export the trailing zeros.

Comment: @Luuk How can this be done via `libreoffice --convert-to csv`?

Comment: This appears to be asking about using the Libreoffice program itself, not about writing code to work with its output. Libreoffice is just an ordinary spreadsheet program; that's not by any means a tool primarily used by programmers. The question also doesn't appear to be about how to write spreadsheet formulas, but only about saving an output file from the program. Simply having a command-line interface for the application doesn't make it "programming" to use it (and there are other sites for that sort of thing anyway, like [unix.se]). In short, I don't see how this is on topic.

Comment: See the documentation on [CSV Filter Parameters](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/ro/text/shared/guide/…). On Windows 10, the following works: `.\soffice --convert-to "csv:Text - txt - csv (StarCalc):44,34,0, , , ,false,false,true,false" --outdir C:\TEMP\ C:\TEMP\round.ods`

Comment: And see Luuk's comment containing the correct hyperlink...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How can I get the proper 1.00 output into the CSV?"
The short answer is you cannot. This is because CSV is an awful file format (see: https://www.google.com/search?q=whyt+is+csv+a+bad+file+format )

But when you have a file in OpenOffice like this (let's name it: `Untitled 1.ods`):
[image]

And you need/want to export it with trailing zeroes, you can do:

```
C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice --convert-to html "Untitled 1.ods"
```

Which produces and Html file named `Untitled 1.html`

After this you can use [xmlstarlet](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to do
this:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m //tr -m td -v . -o "," -b -n "Untitled 1.html"
```

Which produces next output:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,
1,00,2,00,3,00,1,00,2,00,3,00,
4,00,5,00,6,00,4,00,5,00,6,00,
7,00,8,00,9,00,7,00,8,00,9,00,
```

This only works because exporting to HTML keeps the format which was applied to the cells, and exporting to CSV just exports the values, and does not care for any formatting done.

P.S. The output just shows why "Comma Separated Value (CSV)" should never have been invented .

Comment: The long answer would be: "Yes, you can...". See my comment on the question.

Comment: The complete (deep link to) the filter options is: https://help.libreoffice.org/7.4/ro/text/shared/guide/csv_params.html?&DbPAR=SHARED&System=WIN

Comment: I _hate_ the LO docs... thanks for adding the correct link...

Comment: @tohuwawohu: The docs is one of the reasons why I did not know about those filters...